# puppeteer grab all links from separate grid

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to grab all the item links from https://www.homedepot.com/b/Outdoors-Outdoor-Cooking-Grills-Gas-Grills/N-5yc1vZc5t5 with this code, but it only grabs links from '#browse-search-pods-1 and not #browse-search-pods-2. The page layout looks the same for both sections. Ideally I want to get only the links with #was-price, but I haven't tried filtering yet since I can't get all the links.

The results are
[first 12 links]
[]

```
let urls = await page.$$eval('#browse-search-pods-1 .browse-search__pod', links => {
        links = links.map(el => el.querySelector('.header').href)
        return links;          
    });              
console.log(urls);    
urls = await page.$$eval('#browse-search-pods-2 .browse-search__pod', links => {
        links = links.map(el => el.querySelector('.header').href)
        return links;
    });
    console.log(urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second section seems to be lazy-loaded, it will be only available in the DOM once you've scrolled it into view.

You can try to interact with it to force it to be toggled by puppeteer, e.g.:

```js
...
await page.hover('#browse-search-pods-2')
urls = await page.$$eval('#browse-search-pods-2 .browse-search__pod', links => links.map(el => el.querySelector('.header').href))
```

(you may need to apply a waitFor to make sure the content appeared correctly)

Comment: I needed to scroll to end of page before trying to pull links.

Comment: then it is still possible that evaluation happens earlier than the second pod was populated in the DOM, I wrote in my answer that you might need to wait for it to be happened. in your code example it does not happen, even if it is a crucial part of dealing with async page loading.